# Spark SQL insert into select issue

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

```
INSERT INTO hive_table SELECT b.id,a.id FROM hive_table_1 a,hive_table_2 b WHERE a.id BETWEEN b.id1 AND b.id2;
```

execute such SQL on **spark-sql** got errors:

> ERROR CliDriver: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: missing TABLE at 'hive_table' near '<EOF>'; line 1 pos 12
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveQl$.createPlan(HiveQl.scala:289)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.ExtendedHiveQlParser$$anonfun$hiveQl$1.apply(ExtendedHiveQlParser.scala:41)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.ExtendedHiveQlParser$$anonfun$hiveQl$1.apply(ExtendedHiveQlParser.scala:40)

But run ok in hive-cli or beeline.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you are connecting to a different instance?

Comment: no,if so it would be another error message.In fact,I'd got nothing about the exception on google.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a typo in your query - you write a,id instead of a.id to access the field id of the table a.

This code should work properly:

```
INSERT INTO hive_table SELECT b.id,a.id
FROM hive_table_1 a,hive_table_2 b 
WHERE a.id BETWEEN b.id1 AND b.id2;
```

I found your error: spark does not pick hive-site.xml from scratch, 
You have to use a workaround.
Possible workarounds can be found [there](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/v5-3-x/topics/cdh_rn_spark_ki.html)

Comment: u r really carefully,it was my written mistake,not the real problem,but thx either.